# RoR Links Breaking in Production but not Dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few links that are breaking. One, my logout, which I am using the `delete` method with, returns this error:

```
[Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/sign_out". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

I have this in my routes: `get '/users/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'`

And my devise routes look like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions',
                                    registrations: 'registrations',
                                    invitations: 'invitations' }
```

Why is this breaking?

Answer (score 0):

`I have this in my routes: get '/users/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'`

if you want to allow the user to sign out via `GET` method all you have to do is go to `app/config/initializers/devise.rb` and uncomment the line `config.sign_out_via = :get`

OR Try this

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```